# How to fix this error message in pp (parallel python) package

Tags: python-3.x, parallel-processing

I am new to use parallel python, and I'm surprised that there are few documentations about it. I am trying to parallelize random forest implemented by myself. Since my code works well without using pp, I believe I am using pp incorrectly.

I am trying to create 500 trees altogether so that each core builds 100 trees. So outside the for-loop of 'job_submission', I create random forest object whose parameter of ntree is 100. However, I kept getting this error.

```py
    import pp

    class randomforest():
        '''
        SOME METHODS
        '''
        def _grow(self, D):
            '''
            Build a tree
            '''
            return tree

    if __name__ == '__main__':
        '''
        Initialize X_train, Y_train, D
        '''
        job_server = pp.Server(5)
        rf = RandomForest(X_train, Y_train, ntree=100)

        result = []
        forest = []
        n, _ = np.shape(rf.x)
        D = [rf.x[i] + [rf.y[i]] for i in range(n)]
        for i in range(5):
            f = job_server.submit(rf._grow, (D,), ('numpy',))
            result.append(f)
        for job in result:
            forest.append(job())
        rf.forest_ = forest
```

I backtracked these files, but I don't understand why I got the last error in file , line 1.

```
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
 A fatal error has occured during the function execution
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/anaconda3/envs/mvi/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ppworker.py", line 90, in run
    __fname, __fobjs = self.t.creceive(preprocess)
  File "/anaconda3/envs/mvi/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pptransport.py", line 124, in creceive
    self.rcache[hash1] = tuple(map(preprocess, (msg, )))[0]
  File "/anaconda3/envs/mvi/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ppworker.py", line 56, in preprocess
    fobjs = [compile(fsource, '<string>', 'exec') for fsource in fsources]
  File "/anaconda3/envs/mvi/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ppworker.py", line 56, in <listcomp>
    fobjs = [compile(fsource, '<string>', 'exec') for fsource in fsources]
  File "<string>", line 1
    ow(self, dataset):
```